# SmartGwt SelectItem Multiple select programmatically

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I am new in SmartGWT and trying to select items of a SelectItem Widget programmatically. But didn't found a solution for that.

This is what I want:

[image]

This is my current code from the SmartGWT examples:

```
 SelectItem selectMultiple = new SelectItem();
      selectMultiple.setTitle("SelectItem: ");
      selectMultiple.setMultiple(true);
      selectMultiple.setMultipleAppearance(MultipleAppearance.PICKLIST);
      selectMultiple.setValueMap("Cat", "Dog", "Giraffe", "Goat", "Marmoset", "Mouse");
```

How can I select Items programmatically? Found nothing about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [SelectItem#setValues()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/SelectItem.html#setValues%28java.lang.String...%29)

```
selectMultiple.setValues("Dog","Goat");
```